# I measure, draw and do other things - in only five letters!

Tags: riddle, word

> Although in me you may find mistakes and misery
>
> I always measure up to what is expected of me
>
> You can use me to draw
>
> I can also beat you raw
>
> You may need me to plot the right way
>
> Over people I hold sway
>
> I am a five letter word
>
> What I am must be inferred.

This is my first puzzle; feedback is welcomed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you are a

> RULER

although I only have satisfactory explanations for four of those six lines:

Although in me you may find mistakes and misery

> The letters of RULER contain (anagrams of) ERR and RUE. (Thanks to suomynonA for the hint in comments.)

I always measure up to what is expected of me

> You use a ruler for measuring things.

You can use me to draw

> You use a ruler for drawing straight lines.

I can also beat you raw

> In the bad old days of corporal punishment, it was not uncommon for teachers to hit children with rulers. (Thanks to suomynonA for the hint in comments. D'oh!)

You may need me to plot the right way

> Again, used for drawing, especially where accuracy is required as e.g. in plotting graphs or map routes.

Over people I hold sway

> "Ruler" in the sense of king, queen, etc., now.

My (feeble) best guesses at the two lines I don't have good explanations for:

> *Mistakes and misery*: (1) the word ends with -ER which sounds like ERR which means to make mistakes. Or (2) rulers not infrequently make mistakes and inflict misery on their subjects. *Beating you raw*: could again be a reference to the misbehaviour of autocratic rulers (who sometimes do worse to their subjects than just beating them).

But I find those unsatisfactory enough that I fear this answer may be only a clever red herring and have little to do with the intended one...

Comment: Nice! You got the word, and you got half of both of the remaining two ;) A hint for the first clue: **Anagrams** For the other one, think of how the other definition of ruler can also beat a person raw.

Comment: Teachers used to discipline kids with rulers. Thats what i thought of for the beat people raw.

Comment: Back when schools were allowed to use corporal punishment, one of the methods was to hit a kid's knuckles with a ruler. EDIT: @gtwebb beat me to it

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: Explanations of remaining lines added. I feel very stupid about not seeing the school-cruelty one instantly.

Comment: You got them all now, nice work=)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i got so far

> A sword
>  You can draw a sword or beat someone up with it
>  It is useful to plot or conquer as it hold sways of those fearful of death(tyranny)
>  It's purpose is not complicated but always lives up to it, it kills.
>  But in the end, all it brings is misery.

Comment: Sorry, a sword doesn't work because you don't use a sword to draw.

Comment: You need a sword to draw. You can't draw your sword without a sword. It's just not the "draw" you had in mind.

Comment: Maybe... nice try